# JavaFX stage closing with keypress doesn't work with TextField

Tags: java, javafx, textfield, keypress, stage

I want my application to close whenever I press the `F12` button.

Here is my code for this:

```
stage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.F12) 
        System.exit(0);
});
```

It works perfectly until one of my `TextFields` get focus. In such cases `F12` doesn't do anything.
How should I solve this without set this EventHandler for all of my `TextFields`?

Comment: what is the type of the stage field?

Comment: How do you mean? It has a scene, which has different Panes, which have different TextFields.

Comment: [mcve] please .. can't remember if a textfield consumes all pressed, if so it would not reach any parent (including the stage). Use a filter instead.

Comment: @kleopatra You are great. Filter works like charm. Thanks.